# (Calculus) Derivative Thinking Question

Tags: calculus, derivatives, quadratics, tangent-line, slope

Recently, my Calculus and Vectors (Grade 12) teacher gave our class a thinking question/assignment to work on over the march break, and after working on for some time, I've become stuck on it.

**The Question:**

Consider **f(*x*)**, a general quadratic function in standard form, and **g(*x*)** its reciprocal. For which values of ***x*** are the slopes of their respective tangent lines equal?

Consider two cases: one where it is true for exactly one value of ***x***, and the other where it is true for exactly two values of ***x***. In the latter case, you can assume that the steepness a does not equal **0** of **f(*x*)** is equal to both it’s ***y***-intercept and also to the slope of its tangent at ***x*** = **1**.

Find the required conditions on the parameters ***a***,***b***,***c*** in terms of ***a***.

**My Progress So Far:**

So I know that $f(x) = ax^2 +bx + c$ and $g(x) = 1/f(x)$. After I solved for the derivative of each function, I set them both equal to each other and started solving for it. But then I came to a equation of $(ax^2 + bx + c)^2 = -1$ and that doesn't work.

Next I tried something else. Since I know from the 2nd case that $f(x) = c$ and $f(x) = f'(1)$ when a cannot equal 0, I set $c = f'(1)$ and got $c = 2a + b$. But after that, I don't know where to go.

I'm not expecting a full solution, but if anyone could give me a hint for solving this question, I would appreciate it. I know that it says to write everything in terms of a, but I'm not sure how to approach that method.

Comment: I made a typo in solving and so my prior comment did not make sense.  To get your equation $f(x)^2=-1$ you likely made a cancellation on both sides, but what happens if the term you canceled is zero?

Comment: The term that I cancelled was 2ax+b (which is f'(x)), I don't know if the term cancelled can be zero since I do not know the unknowns. (I apologize if I didn't answer your question).

Comment: So you got $-f'(x)=f'(x)f(x)^2$ and want to find an $x$ where this is possible. It is not possible if $f'(x) \neq 0$ as you already showed and so the only way possible is if $f'(x)=0$. So then for what values of $a,b$ is it possible to have $2ax+b=0$?

Comment: Now that made a lot more sense to me. So then the values of a and b would both have to equal 0 in order to get f'(x) = 0.

Comment: If we needed $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$, then we would require $a=b=0$. However, you don't need $f'(x)=0$ for all $x$, you just want there to _exist at least one $x$_ for which $f'(x)=0$. Assuming $a$ and $b$ are any values that satsify $a\neq 0$,  the answer below (which I upvoted when it came out) shows that this works for $x^* = -b/(2a)$. Now if $a=0$, we require $b=0$, which makes sense since then the function and its reciprocal are just constants.  Another subtle issue is that you need to ensure $f(-b/(2a))\neq 0$, else the answer does not apply as the reciprocal is not defined there.

Comment: FYI: My first comment above "I made a typo..." appeared before the egreg answer, but the egreg answer appeared only a few minutes after. I have no idea how egreg typed up such a detailed answer (together with a graph!) in such a short time...I think all of that was within 10 minutes of your posting the question!

Answer (score 10):

If $g(x)=1/f(x)$, then, by the chain rule,
$$
g'(x)=-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}
$$
Thus, assuming of course that $f(x)\ne0$, we have $g'(x)=f'(x)$ if and only if
$$
-\frac{f'(x)}{f(x)^2}=f'(x)
$$
which can only happen if $f'(x)=0$. Indeed, if $f'(x)\ne0$, the equation becomes $f(x)^2=-1$, which is exactly the condition you find.

You can observe that this is independent of $f$ being a quadratic polynomial.

In your particular case, the condition is $x=-b/(2a)$, provided that $f(-b/(2a))\ne0$ (or $g(-b/(2a))$ would be undefined.

[image]